# Grep and print only matching word and the next words

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I have a text file, install.history

```
Wed June 20 23:16:32 CDT 2014, EndPatch, FW_6.0.0, SUCCESS
```

I would only need to print out the word starting from `EndPatch` to the end that is `FW_6.0.0, SUCCESS`
The command below that I have only prints out `EndPatch`, so what do I need to do so that it prints out the remaining of the words so that my result would be:

`EndPatch, FW_6.0.0, SUCCESS`

Here is the command that I have:

```
  grep -oh "EndPatch[[:alpha:]]*" 'install.history'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is arguably, easier to do with `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/.*EndPatch, //p' install.history
```

to get the word after EndPatch:

```
sed -n 's/.*EndPatch, \([^,]*\).*/\1/p' install.history
```

or:

```
sed -n 's/.*EndPatch, //p' install.history | cut -d, -f
```

Comment: Or just `sed 's/.*EndPatch, //g' file`

Comment: Hi @perreal, what if I only wanted the next word after "EndPatch", which is FW_6.0.0?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below grep command to get everything from `EndPatch` upto the last,

```
grep -oP 'EndPatch, (.*)$' file
```

or

```
grep -o 'EndPatch.*$' file
```

Example:

```
$ grep -oP 'EndPatch, (.*)$' file
EndPatch, FW_6.0.0, SUCCESS
$ grep -o 'EndPatch.*$' file
EndPatch, FW_6.0.0, SUCCESS
```

Or

You could try the below command to get all the characters which was just after to `EndPatch,`

```
$ grep -oP 'EndPatch, \K(.*)$' file
FW_6.0.0, SUCCESS
```

Comment: Hi Avinash, I tried this out - $ grep -oP 'EndPatch, \K(.*)$' file. And the output is "EndPatch, FW_6.0.0, SUCCESS" instead of "FW_6.0.0, SUCCESS". Any ideas?

Comment: Its capital k not a small letter k.

Comment: This is my command, grep -oP 'EndPatch, \K(.*)$' /homenfs/sandbox/FU_HOME/install.history >> Output.txt
But it is not working, it shows no output.

Answer (score 0):

You need `grep -e` for regular expression matching

```
grep -oh 'install.history' -e "EndPatch[[:alpha:]]*"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`

```
awk -F "EndPatch, " '{print FS$2}' file
EndPatch, FW_6.0.0, SUCCESS
```