# awk: select first column and value in column after matching word

Tags: bash, awk, sed, text-processing

I have a .csv where each row corresponds to a person (first column) and attributes with values that are available for that person. I want to extract the names and values a particular attribute for persons where the attribute is available. The doc is structured as follows:

```
name,attribute1,value1,attribute2,value2,attribute3,value3
joe,height,5.2,weight,178,hair,
james,,,,,,
jesse,weight,165,height,5.3,hair,brown
jerome,hair,black,breakfast,donuts,height,6.8
```

I want a file that looks like this:

```
name,attribute,value
joe,height,5.2
jesse,height,5.3
jerome,height,6.8
```

Using [this earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24379059/grep-and-print-only-matching-word-and-the-next-words), I've tried a few different `awk` methods but am still having trouble getting both the first column and then whatever column has the desired value for the attribute (say height). For example the following returns everything.

```
awk -F "height," '{print $1 "," FS$2}' file.csv
```

I could `grep` only the rows with height in them, but I'd prefer to do everything in a single line if I can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```bash
cat attrib.awk

BEGIN {
   FS=OFS=","
   print "name,attribute,value"
}
NR > 1 && match($0, k "[^,]+") {
   print $1, substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-1)
}

# then run it as
awk -v k=',height,' -f attrib.awk file

name,attribute,value
joe,height,5.2
jesse,height,5.3
jerome,height,6.8

# or this one
awk -v k=',weight,' -f attrib.awk file

name,attribute,value
joe,weight,178
jesse,weight,165
```

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`. Simple explanation would be, using GNU `awk` and setting `RS`(record separator) to `^[^,]*,height,[^,]*` and then printing RT as per requirement to get expected output.

```bash
awk -v RS='^[^,]*,height,[^,]*' 'RT{print RT}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -v attr="height" '
BEGIN  { FS=OFS="," }
FNR==1 { print "name", "attribute", "value"; next }
       { for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2)                         # loop through even-numbered fields
             if ($i == attr) {                        # if field value is an exact match to the "attr" variable then ...
                print $1,$i,$(i+1)                    # print current name, current field and next field to stdout
                next                                  # no need to check rest of current line; skip to next input line
             }
       }
' file.csv
```

**NOTE:** this assumes the input value (`height` in this example) will match exactly (including same capitalization) with a field in the file

This generates:

```
name,attribute,value
joe,height,5.2
jesse,height,5.3
jerome,height,6.8
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest a `sed` one-liner:

```
sed -n 's/^\([^,]*\).*\(,height,[^,]*\).*/\1\2/p' file.csv
```

Comment: cool to see it in sed

Answer (score 2):

With a [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) one-liner:

```
$ perl -lne '
    print "name,attribute,value" if $.==1;
    print "$1,$2" if /^(\w+).*(height,\d+\.\d+)/
' file
```

## output

```
name,attribute,value
joe,height,5.2
jesse,height,5.3
jerome,height,6.8
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk` accepts variable-value arguments following  a `-v` flag before the script. Thus, the name of the required attribute can be passed into an awk script using the general pattern:

```
awk -v attr=attribute1 ' {} ' file.csv
```

Inside the script, the value of the passed variable is reference by the variable name, in this case `attr`.

Your criteria are to print column 1, the first column containing the name, the column corresponding to the  required header value, and the column immediately after that column (holding the matched values).

Thus, the following script allows you to fish out the column headed "attribute1" and it's next neighbour:

```
awk -v attr=attribute1 ' BEGIN {FS=","} /attr/{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i == attr) col=i;} {print $1","$col","$(col+1)} ' data.txt
```

result:

```
name,attribute1,value1
joe,height,5.2
james,,
jesse,weight,165
jerome,hair,black
```

another column (attribute 3):

```
awk -v attr=attribute3 ' BEGIN {FS=","} /attr/{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i == attr) col=i;} {print $1","$col","$(col+1)} ' awkNames.txt
```

result:

```
name,attribute3,value3
joe,hair,
james,,
jesse,hair,brown
jerome,height,6.8
```

Just change the value of the `-v attr=` argument for the required column.